# Ensure redux state is current across browser sessions

Tags: reactjs, redux, state

What is the best practice for refreshing state across browser sessions without a third party library? I need to make sure data is current before triggering a download on an object in state. I have tried using multiple useEffect's (one to update the data, one to trigger the download) but the state function calls the download on the state in props before updating the object. I know state is set asynchronously but haven't been able to resolve this issue.

```
function DownloadButton(props){
  const {selected} = props;
  let selectedFile = selected ? props.all.files[selected] : null;
  const [downloaded, setDownloaded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(selected && downloaded === true){
      selectedFile.download();
    }
      setDownloaded(false);   
  }, [props.all, downloaded]);

  return(
     <DownloadButton 
        onClick={() => {
          //trigger refresh of props.all
          props.refresh();
          //below works if wrapped in setTimeout
          setDownloaded(true);
        }}
     />
  );

}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    all: state.all
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    refresh: () => dispatch({type: "GET_ALL"})
  } 
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DownloadButton);
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "refreshing state across browser sessions"? Is your app running in multiple browser tabs? Do you want to persist redux state after closing a browser tab/window?

Comment: Are you waiting for `props.refresh()` to finish some async work?

Comment: @timotgl exactly, users can be editing a file in multiple tabs, and if they switch to another tab to download the file, I want the latest version to be downloaded. The idea is to invoke the redux action that calls the latest data from the server before every download. The props.refresh() triggers an async action "REFRESH_CALLED" which has a success type "REFRESH_RECEIVED", which sets the props.all.file data. My problem is the download is called before the props.all.file data is updated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the component is a bit too involved with the refresh mechanism, so I'd delegate that to a redux action instead:

```
// async download action
const downloadFile = (fileName) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  await dispatch(refresh());
  const file = getState().all.files[fileName];
  file.download(); // it's not recommended to have functions in redux state btw
};

function DownloadButton(props) {
  const { selected, downloadFile } = props;

  return(
    <>
      {!!selected && <DownloadButton onClick={() => downloadFile(selected)} />}
    </>
  );
}

const mapDispatchToProps = { downloadFile };
```